# How to share a Python project that uses 3rd party packages

Tags: python, pip, package

I have a Python script that uses 3rd-party packages I've manually installed using pip.

I want to share my python script with a co-worker but don't want them to have to manually install packages with pip (they aren't very technical).

Is there a way to package up my Python script and dependencies so that the user isn't burdened with manually installing the package dependencies?

Comment: You can make a standalone executable. Check for `pyinstaller`

Answer (score 0):

Well assuming he can run a vanilla python script, you can just include the pip installs in the script itself

```
import sys
import subprocess
# implement pip as a subprocess:
subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', '<packagename>'])
```

Just need to replace the appropriate pieces for your use case

Comment: Thank you but I specifically asked for a solution that does not require the user to run a Python script. This is someone who has never seen a command prompt before. ;-)

Comment: @Offswitch sorry, I was confused because you only mentioned installing the python packages, not python itself.

Comment: No worries - I definitely wasn't clear enough. Thank you again!